# Django Rest Framework: Default foreign key to value from request

Tags: django, foreign-keys, django-rest-framework

A **User** belongs to an **Office**. A **User** can create a **Contact**. A **Contact** belongs to an **Office**.

I want the office_id of the Contact to default to the current User's office.

At the moment, the way I'm doing this is by overriding ModelViewSet create method:

In my views.py

```
def create(self, request):
    contact_data = request.data
    contact_data['office'] = request.user.userprofile.office.id # This is the only line I added
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=contact_data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    self.perform_create(serializer)
    headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

But this approach doesn't feel quite right and it's a lot of code for what it does. Any idea of how I can achieve this in a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hook on `.perform_create`:

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(office=self.request.user.userprofile.office.id)
```

but you'll probably have to also change the `office` field in the `serializer` to `required=False` in order to make it pass the `.is_valid`.

Another solution is to alter the `request.data` and then call the `create` method:

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    request.data['office'] = request.user.userprofile.office.id
    return super(ViewClassName, self).create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Hi Todor, thanks for your reply. I chose the second solution (felt cleaner to me). Can you please explain the "return super(ViewClassName, self).create(request, *args, **kwargs)" bit ? I know what super is in OOP but here it looks like it's a recursive function...?

Comment: Every `child` class can have access to it's `parent` methods. `super(YourViewClassName, self)` returns the `parent` of your `ViewSet` class. So after we made the desired changes, we use it (the parent) to call it's `create` method *(parent.create)* to do the rest job. Hmm i hope that explains it? If it's still unclear try to read some articles about the topic, for example start with this one: [Inheritance Versus Composition](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex44.html)